# Cannot install calcurse on RHEL8

Tags: rhel, yum, dnf, ncurses

I am unable to install calcurse on RHEL8.1. The error is that the ./configure file in the tarball does not recognize `ncurses` as installed:

```
# git clone https://github.com/lfos/calcurse
# cd calcurse
# ./configure
[...]
checking for initscr in -lncursesw... no
checking for initscr in -lncurses... no
configure: error: Either ncurses or ncursesw library is required to build calcurse!
```

The package `ncurses` is however installed:

```
# yum -y install ncurses
[...]
Package ncurses-6.1-7.20180224.el8.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

Answer (score 3):

`ncurses` is the runtime package; to build software with ncurses, you need to install the development package, `ncurses-devel`.